# wp_list_pages() not showing on posts

Tags: categories, menus, wp-list-pages, sub-menu

I have the following code showing up a sub-menu on my website (in my `header.php` file) that shows all well and good, however when I open up a post it dissapears:

```
<div id="dep-menu">
    <?php global $post;
    if (!is_front_page()) { // so I don't display a link on the homepage saying "Homepage"
        if($post->post_parent) { //if page has parent
            $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&include=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); //include a link to the parent
            $children.= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); //add the child pages
        } else {
            $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&include=".$post->ID."&echo=0");//parent link
            $children.= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");//children
        }
        if ($children) { ?>
            <ul>
            <?php echo $children; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php }
    }
?>
</div>
```

This works all well and good for my pages. The pages on this site are effectively `get x posts from y category and display title and excerpt`. No page is more than 2 deep cat wise meaning no url is more than `domain.com/cat-x/cat-y/` and the menu works on those pages.

When I open a post with the url scheme of `domain.com/cat-x/post-title/` the menu drops off.

**BEGIN EDIT**

As there seemed to be some confusion, my page hierarchyis like so:

```
parent 1
    child 1-1
    child 1-2
parent 2
    child 2-1
    child 2-1
```

`parent 1` corresponds to a category name and when clicked a submenu showing `parent 1 | child 1-1 | child 2-1` shows up each displaying all the posts in their namesake categories.

However when I click on a post the submenu disappears, and I need it to stay persistent.

**END EDIT**

Essentially, how do I get the menu to display again? As far as I can tell it should stay there as it still fits the url schema and has the same category.

Comment: Did you get all Contents wp_list_pages( $args );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your menu is pages oriented.
pages have parents and the query asks for the parent and the siblings.

When accessing posts, posts have no hirarcy, wp_list_pages will not work and you cannot query posts by parent.

The big question is what you'd like to display when accessing a single post...

if you want to display the main site navigation yuo can do this:

```
<div id="dep-menu">
<?php global $post;
if (!is_front_page()) { // so I don't display a link on the homepage saying "Homepage"
    if (is_page()) {
        if($post->post_parent) { //if page has parent
            $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&include=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); //include a link to the parent
            $children.= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); //add the child pages
        } else {
            $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&include=".$post->ID."&echo=0");//parent link
            $children.= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");//children
       }
    } else {
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&echo=0&depth=1"); //list top level pages
    }
    if ($children) { ?>
        <ul>
        <?php echo $children; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php }
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to show the menu like it does on the page preceding it so if I was viewing a Covered Call Report post the menu would show `Covered Call | Report ASX Recommendation | Trade History | US Recommendation` as if it were a page.

Comment: i.e. you want to list the other posts in the same category. Am I right ?

Comment: I have edited OP to try and explain a little better